# How to check index numbers from database using Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I've got a system built in Django which receives data. I store the data as follows:

```
 id | sensor | message_id | value
----+--------+------------+-------
 1  | A      | 1          | xxx    
 2  | A      | 2          | xxx
 3  | A      | 3          | xxx
 4  | B      | 1          | xxx
 5  | B      | 2          | xxx
 6  | B      | 4          | xxx
 7  | B      | 7          | xxx
```

We expect the `message_id` to increases by one per sensor with every subsequent message. As you can see, the message_ids for sensor B are: 1, 2, 4, 7. This means the messages with numbers 3, 5 and 6 are missing for sensor B. In this case we would need to investigate the missing messages, especially if there are many missing. So I now want a way to know about these missing messages when it happens.

So I want do a check whether a message is missing in the past five minutes. I would expect an output that says something like:

> 3 messages are missing for sensor B in the last 5 minutes. The following ids are missing: 3, 5, 6

The simplest way I thought of doing this is by querying the message_id for one sensor and then looping over them to check whether any number is skipped. I thought of something like this:

```
five_minutes_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=5)
queryset = MessageData.objects.filter(created__gt=five_minutes_ago).filter(sensor='B').order_by('message_id')
last_message_id = None
for md in queryset:
    if last_message_id is None:
        last_message_id = md.message_id
    else:
        if md.message_id != last_message_id + 1:
            missing_messages = md.message_id - last_message_id - 1
            print(f"{missing_messages} messages missing for sensor {md.sensor}")
```

But since I've got hundreds of sensors this seems like it's not the best way to do it. It might even be possible to do in the SQL itself, but I'm unaware of a way to do so.

How could I efficiently do this?

Comment: What does it mean when this happens?

Comment: @Strawberry - It means a message has been gone missing somewhere in the process.

Comment: And what should the desired result look like? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, what if it's the first message that goes missing?? Or the last one!?!

Comment: @Strawberry - I edited the question to explain that number 3 is missing for sensor B. If the first message in that 5 minutes goes missing that is a pity. I'll probably check the last 10 minutes every 5 minutes to fix that. The main question is now how I can more efficiently check this for all the sensors.

Comment: @kramer65 Do you just want to check if any number is missing or you want the total number of rows(ids) that are missing? also, I think by your code if the message_ids are like `[1,2,3,6,9]` then the output will be 6-3-1, i.e. `2 messages are missing for md.sensor` and then for the same md.sensor it will print 9-6-1, ie. `2 messages are missing`. Do you want output like that or just `4 messages are missing from md.sensor`? The optimal solution would be very different for each scenario.

Comment: @KaushalSharma - Good point. I'd like to output that 4 messages are missing.

Comment: I think you should amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @Strawberry - I edited the question to state more clearly what I'm expecting. Does this make it clear to you?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry - Actually we're using Postgres. So I removed the mysql tag. May I ask why the mysql version would be relevant?

Comment: Prior to version 8, you would have been unable to use Common Table Expressions in MySQL, which would be one way of solving  this.

Comment: @Strawberry - In Postgresql there are Common Table Expressions. Do you have a suggestion for how to use that to solve this challenge?

Comment: I'm sure there is - but I don't know Postgres, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, I have added comments above the line for the logic, feel free to comment in case of any query.

```
five_minutes_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=5)
queryset = MessageData.objects.filter(created__gt=five_minutes_ago).filter(sensor='B').order_by('message_id')

# rows that should ideally be there if no message_id was missing, i.e. equal to last message_id
ideal_num_of_rows = queryset.last().message_id

# total number of message_id present
total_num_of_row_present = queryset.count()

# number of missing message_ids 
num_of_missing_message_ids = ideal_num_of_rows - total_num_of_rows_present - 1
```

Comment: Do note that `.filter(created__gt=five_minutes_ago)` just might filter out some of the instances of `MessageData` for the sensor giving a wrong count in that case.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat valid point, I just used the queryset in the question.  My main reason for the answer was to simplify the logic for the missing message_ids

Comment: This is quite a good point. But it's not actually testing the order of the data. In some cases, data can arrive later. But it should always arrive in order. So if the last 5 messages are missing, that is still okay, since the order of the message_id's is not violated. But thanks for your suggestion anyway, I'll probably use this check as well.

Comment: @kramer65 can you explain with a test case and the expected output? also thanks for upvoting.

Comment: I edited the question to explain better what kind of message I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with a single SQL statement. The following generates for an array for of missing message ids and the number of missing messages for each sensor. This is done in 3 steps:

1. Get the minimum and maximum message ids.
2. Generate a dense list of message id needed.
3. Left join the actual sensor messages with the dense list and select
   only those in the dense list not in the actual table. Count the
   items selected.

```
with sensor_range (sensor, min_msg_id, max_msg_id) as           -- 1 get necessary message range 
     ( select sensor
            , min(message_id)
            , max(message_id) 
         from sensor_messages 
        group by sensor
       -- where message_ts > current_timestamp - interval '5 min) 
     )  --select * from sensor_range;
     , sensor_series (sensor, msg_id) as                        -- 2 generate list of needed messages_id 
       ( select sensor, n 
           from sensor_range  sr 
           cross join generate_series( sr.min_msg_id
                                     , sr.max_msg_id
                                     , 1
                                     ) gs(n)
        ) --select * from sensor_series;
select ss.sensor
     , array_agg(ss.msg_id)  missing_message_ids                 --3 Identify messing message_id and count their number 
     , array_length(array_agg(ss.msg_id),1) missing_messages_count
  from sensor_series        ss
  left join sensor_messages sm 
         on (    ss.sensor = sm.sensor 
             and sm.message_id = ss.msg_id
            )
where sm.message_id is null 
group by ss.sensor 
order by ss.sensor;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f61d345772522cf2bf7f981e50fd1e8d). This could be packaged into an SQL function that returns a table if desired. A good [reference](https://heavylion.medium.com/functions-that-return-tables-other-options-f5be86590da).

Your description mentions a time range, but your data does not have a timestamp column. The query has a comment for handling this.